# gulp reference to original source after minification

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify

Once magnification is done, and let's say I had some bug,

and I want the console of browser to point me to original source so I could see the problem clearly instead of minified lines of code.

**Script.js + many more files (concatenation plus minification)**

```
   var somevar = 4
   console.log(someVar) //misspelled var name
```

console will take me to this file

**script.min.js**

```
var somevar=4;console.log(someVar)
```

I've seen some `.map` files with some js libraries, don't know how they work.

Can someone advise how can the console of a browser can refer to original source in case of an error /problem in a minified file.

```
gulp.task("app", function() {
    var app = [
        "js/libs/abc.js",
        "js/file1.js",
        "js/file2.js"
    ];

    gulp.src(app)
        .pipe(concat("app.min.js"))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("js"))
});
```

Comment: Which tool are you using for minifying? That tool also has to create a source map, either inline or as extra files. More about source maps: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: I'm using gulp, but don't know how can it generate .map files

Comment: Gulp is not a minifier. It's just a system to register tasks and stream files. It seems you are using uglify. See http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/codegen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this to your dev dependencies
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps

```
gulp.src(app)
        .pipe(concat("app.min.js"))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("js"))
```

Make sure the generated JavaScript file, example.js, has the source mapping url at the end as follows:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=example.js.map
```